# ¿Cómo hago una sobrecarga de constructores?

Tags: php

estoy intentando hacer sobrecarga de constructores, de tal manera que se puedan instanciar objetos con propiedades y objetos vacíos.

Tengo algo como esto:

```
function __construct($nif,$nombre,$primerApellido,$segundoApellido){
        $this->nif=$nif;
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->primerApellido=$primerApellido;
        $this->segundoApellido=$segundoApellido;
        global $numeroAlumnos;
        $numeroAlumnos++;
    }
    function __construct0(){/*Sobrecarga de constructores para utilizar métodos set sin usar
                           el constructor anterior*/

    }
```

Pero me sale este error, como si no me dejase:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Alumno::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios_POO\Ejercicio04\Index.php on line 4 and exactly 4 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios_POO\Ejercicio04\Alumno.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios_POO\Ejercicio04\Index.php(4): Alumno->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ejercicios_POO\Ejercicio04\Alumno.php on line 5
```

Lo he estado consultando y veo que no se puede en PHP hacer esto. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

**En Php no puedes sobrecargar el constructor**, puedes hacer crear el constructor y una método setAlumno de la siguiente forma:

```
function __construct(){
}

public function setAlumno($nif,$nombre,$primerApellido,$segundoApellido) {
        $this->nif=$nif;
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
        $this->primerApellido=$primerApellido;
        $this->segundoApellido=$segundoApellido;
}
```

Por otra parte las variables globales no son una buena idea, puedes plantearlo de otra manera, si tienes un array de objetos Alumno, puedes saber el número contando el **número de elementos del array con count**.